# How to select distinct keywords from database without specifying any keywords

Tags: distinct, keyword

I am saving in a database column more keywords separated by comma
ex: aaaa, bbbb, cccc ....

There are many rows:

ex:
 row 1 = aaaa, bbbb
 row 2 = aaaa,cccc,ddddd.. 
 etc.

I would like to obtain an array with all different keywords (no duplicates).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you'll want to SELECT DISTINCT off of the results of a PIVOT or UNPIVOT function. Some googling on those terms may be useful.

Comment: In SQL? What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

**Create table :**

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO tablename VALUES
(1, 'aaaa,bbbb'),
(2, 'aaaa,cccc,dddd');

CREATE TABLE numbers (
  n INT PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO numbers VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6);
```

**Fire query :**

```
SELECT group_concat(name) as result
FROM
(
SELECT distinct name 
FROM
(
SELECT
  tablename.id,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1) name
FROM
  numbers INNER JOIN tablename
  ON CHAR_LENGTH(tablename.name)
     -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(tablename.name, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
ORDER BY
  id, n
) tab1
) tab2;
```

Comment: I don't know why, but your example doesn't work for me.

Comment: what database are you using, this is tested on mysql ?

Comment: I don't know why, but your example doesn't work for me. 
Either you did not understand the result I wanted or I have edited wrongly your example. 

Could you please explain me in more detail the example you have given?

My table name:  jobs_details 
My column name: keywords
I don't have an exact number of registered words per rows, one row can have two keywords ( ex: aaaa, ddddd) , other row can have four (ex: aaaa, bbbb,gggg, kkkkk)

and the result I want to be an array like the one below:

array(aaaa,bbbb,dddd,gggg,kkkkk); all distinct words

Comment: Ok, now try with the edited answer, it will work for you.

Comment: Now it's working, Thanks!


I made some changes, I am using TRIM to exclude space between words to have 100% distinct words and also removed " group_concat" because I want an array with each word and an index for each of them ( I have used a foreach for this)

Comment: <pre>
SELECT distinct keywords
                FROM
                    (
                    SELECT
                      jobs_details.job_id,
                      TRIM(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(jobs_details.keywords, ',', numbers.n), ',', -1)) keywords
                    FROM
                      numbers INNER JOIN jobs_details
                      ON CHAR_LENGTH(jobs_details.keywords)
                         -CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(jobs_details.keywords, ',', ''))>=numbers.n-1
                    ORDER BY
                      job_id, n
                    ) tab1
</pre>